# How to put table inside of table?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I want to create a  simple price list which in the second item has two child list.
and all price column must be text align=rigth and item must be text align = left

do you have any idea how to do this.
I want some thing like this.
[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<table style="width:100%" >
  <tr>
    <td>one</td>
    <td>100$</td> 

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>two

               <table style="width:100%" >
   <tr>
     <td>three</td>
     <td>300$</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td>four</td>
     <td>400$</td>
   </tr>
   </table>
    </td>

    <td></td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>five</td>
    <td>500$</td>

  </tr>

</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can use rowspan colspan to merge rows or columns together.

Answer (score 2):

Use `colspan=2` for the cell into which you nest the sub-table, and add the approriate CSS properties:

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td:nth-child(2) {
  text-align: right;
}

table table td:nth-child(1) {
  padding-left: 20%;
}
```

```html
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <td>one</td>
    <td>100$</td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">
      two
      <table style="width:100%">
        <tr>
          <td>three</td>
          <td>300$</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>four</td>
          <td>400$</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>five</td>
    <td>500$</td>

  </tr>

</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

```css
tr{
  display: block;
}
td{
  min-width: 100px;
}
td:nth-child(2){
  text-align:right;
}
td > li{
  padding-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr style="border-bottom: 2px solid black;">
    <td>one</td>
    <td>100$</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>two</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><li>three</li></td>
    <td>300$</td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="border-bottom: 2px solid black;">
    <td><li>four</li></td>
    <td>300$</td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="border-bottom: 2px solid black;">
    <td>five</td>
    <td>400$</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I wanna help you.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `<tbody>` tag around `<tr>` inside `<table>` and just put another table inside `<td>`.

P.S
You shuld take a look at CSS matrix, it might make this a lot easier...

Answer (score 0):

for table header use this structure

```
<thead>
    <tr>
       <th>your header text</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
```

for table footer

```
<tfoot>
   <tr>
      <td> your footer text</td>
   </tr>
</tfoot>
```